# Routing subdomains with AWS and Route 53

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, nameserver

I am following these instructions from Amazon: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html#CreateZoneNewSubdomain

As I need to route a subdomain to a GitLab server we have setup. The parent domain is hosted on 123Reg (let's say it's `example.com`), so I have edited the nameservers of `example.com` to the four name servers that Route 53 has given me in my hosted zone for `here.example.com`. This works and the subdomain takes me to my GitLab instance.

Unfortunatley, it also breaks my parent domain, so `example.com` no longer works.

What do I need to do on 123Reg? Do I still need to add an A record for `here.example.com`? Should I add the parent domain to route 53 as well?

Or is this just going to take some time to propagate?

Comment: I'm have the same issue. Looks like 123-Reg doesn't offer the ability to add NS records for a subdomain.

I'm looking at alternative DNS providers now. I've been with 123-Reg for around 18 years!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delegate the subdomain (`here.example.com`) only to Route 53.

For that you need to:

**On Route 53:**

- Delete the the hosted zone you already created (`example.com`),
- Create a new hosted zone `here.example.com`,

**On 123Reg:**

- Create a new entry and call it `here` (based on your `here.example.com`),
- Give it a NS type and point it to the 4 DNS servers Route 53 assigned to you when you created the hosted zone, (you may need to create the same entry 4 times or just put multiple values depending on the service you are using)

With this config, all `xyz.here.example.com` (`*.here.example.com`) will be created on Route 53

> **Note:** If you are pointing the naked domain to a CNAME, this won't work. You need to use ALIAS or an A record.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The issue with your answer is that 123Reg does not allow me to set NS records on a subdomain. In the end I removed completely the hosted zone from Route 53 and just added the A Name record to 123Reg. I would like to migrate everything over to Route 53 at some point.

Comment: This is very odd. A domain registrar should support delegation of subdomains. This is very limiting!

Comment: I couldn't see a way to add the NS values to only the subdomain

Comment: I checked online and it seems many users faced this with 123Reg.